# Crash after going into wire frame mode 2.8

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Has anyone else been crashing in 2.8 once they go into wire frame mode?

I have two different files that do this and every other one is fine

I just realized its only when I snap into either front or side view using the num pad, weird

Comment: Not for me. Have had buggy files before. Recommend trying to append objects from broken files into a new file.

Comment: Every new file just does the same thing with in a few minutes of being created

Comment: Please clarify, question mentions only two files crash.  Comment above suggests, open blender, save as ... crash?  Open blender from a system terminal. See if there is any output before crash or  If there is a crash log `/tmp/blender_crash.txt` (blender for untitled file, filename otherwise)

Comment: ... and post in question.  It's near on impossible to answer why your blender crashes, on (n) particular files. My suggestion re appending is salvaging whatever mesh, rig, materials you really want to keep from the rogue files by appending them into a clean shiny new file, (one by one save and test might find the offensive object).  When new to blender it is dead easy to bloat out a file with unused data.   Also since blender 2.8 is such a new beast ( i build from source) look for updates regularly or somewhere to get nightly builds.